# Cofactor theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

Shilov on page 12 says determinant $D=a_{1j}A_{1j}+a_{2j}A_{2j}+...+a_{nj}A_{nj}...(I)$ is an **identity** in the quantities $a_{1j}, a_{2j},..., a_{nj}$.  Therefore it remains valid if we replace $a_{ij} (i = 1, 2,. . . , n)$ by any other quantities.  The quantities $A_{1j}, A_{2j},..., A_{nj}$ remain unchanged when such a replacement is made, since **they do not depend** on the elements $a_{ij}$.

Quantity $A_{ij}$ is called the cofactor of the element $a_{ij}$ of the determinant $D$.

My question,from the equation (I) we see that all $\Large A$s are multiplied with specific $\Large a$s, not just any $\Large a$, then how did he conclude the above statement? .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I'm guessing that part of your confusion stems from not treating $j$ as constant in this statement.]

Consider expansion of the matrix along a certain column $j$ (fixed number).

The values of $A_{ij}$ do not involve the entries of the $j$th column, hence may be treated as a constant.

Then the equation for the determinant of the matrix is a linear sum of $a_{ij}$. This equation has the same coefficients regardless of what values of $a_{ij}$ we choose to use.

Note that the determinant of the matrix will change as you change the entries of the $j$th column.

Answer (score 1):

The identity (I) uses the elements $a_{1j}, a_{2j} \ldots$, which of course for the matrix have specific values. What the statement means is that if those values, and only those values, are changed in the matrix, the new determinant is valid for the new matrix.